Is dash cam video of others' traffic infractions useable as evidence by the police?
If my dashcam captures footage of someone driving very recklessly or other driving infraction, along with their licence plate, can the police/prosecution use that evidence if I were to report the infraction to the police?

Just to be clear, you don't mean that reckless driver hitting you and/or causing you to have an accident do you?  Because there are many videos online about dash cams being used to resolve "he said, she said" situations.

@PeterM, no, I don't mean them causing an accident but if my footage of them gets them a citation, hopefully it will stop them before they DO cause an accident or worse, kills someone.  A lot of times, it feels like there are no police around when a ticket should be given to someone who clearly doesn't care about safety when driving.  Even if their actions don't directly affect me, if I catch them road raging with someone else and my footage can get the hot head off the road, we will all be safer.

united-states

can the police/prosecution use that evidence if I were to report the
infraction to the police?

Yes. Someone must authenticate the video to assure with testimony that it isn't fabricated and is what it appears to be, but that's it.

It happens more than you think.  People post bad driver videos they captured on YouTube.  Then someone in that jurisdiction sees it, gets mad about it, then has them charged.

In switzerland no. There has been a supreme court ruling a while ago where a woman was driving aggressively behind someone with a dashcam, overtook them and brake checked them and finally went over a double safety line. All was filmed by the cameras of the person getting harassed and the previous courts had convicted the woman based on the footage. Supreme court overturned it saying you cannot use camera footage in court (at least in a criminal matters, not sure about civil cases) that was obtained without the other parties consent and dashcams are usually not obviously recognizable. They left an (potential) exception for serious crimes (i.e. murder, terrorism, rape or similar) if it could also be obtained by authorities, but not for something like a traffic violation.
Here is the press communication of the supreme court (english translation below):
https://www.bger.ch/files/live/sites/bger/files/pdf/de/archive/6B_1188_2018_2019_10_10_T_d_08_00_08.pdf

Verurteilung aufgrund von Dashcam-Aufzeichnungen: Beschwerde von Fahrzeuglenkerin gutgeheissen
Das Bundesgericht hebt die Verurteilung einer Fahrzeuglenkerin auf, die auf Basis der Dashcam-Aufzeichnungen eines
anderen Verkehrsteilnehmers der mehrfachen Verletzung der Verkehrsregeln schuldig gesprochen worden war. Als
Beweismittel fällt die Verwertung der in Missachtung des Datenschutzgesetzes erlangten Aufnahmen bereits ausser
Betracht, weil es sich bei den fraglichen Verkehrsdelikten nicht um schwere Straftaten handelt.
Ob eine beweismässige Verwertung der Aufzeichnungen im Falle einer schweren Straftat zulässig wäre, hatte das
Bundesgericht nicht zu entscheiden. Die Betroffene war vom Bezirksgericht Bülach 2018 auf Basis der
Dashcam-Aufzeichnungen eines anderen Verkehrsteilnehmers wegen mehrfacher, teilweise grober
Verkehrsregelverletzung zu einer bedingten Geldstrafe sowie einer Busse von 4000 Franken verurteilt worden. Das
Obergericht des Kantons Zürich bestätigte das Urteil.
Das Bundesgericht heisst die Beschwerde der Frau gut und hebt das Urteil des Obergerichts auf. Die privaten
Dashcam-Aufzeichnungen wurden in Missachtung des Datenschutzgesetzes (DSG) und damit rechtswidrig erlangt. Da die
Erstellung von Aufnahmen aus einem Fahrzeug heraus für andere Verkehrsteilnehmer nicht ohne weiteres erkennbar
ist, handelt es sich um eine heimliche Datenverarbeitung im Sinne von Artikel 4 Absatz 4 DSG, die eine
Persönlichkeitsverletzung darstellt.
Die Strafprozessordnung (StPO) enthält Bestimmungen zur Verwertbarkeit von Beweisen, die von staatlichen Behörden
rechtswidrig erlangt wurden. Nicht explizit geregelt wird in der StPO, wieweit diese Beweisverbote auch greifen,
wenn Private Beweismittel sammeln.
Gemäss Rechtssprechung des Bundesgerichts dürfen von Privaten rechtswidrig erhobene Beweismittel nur dann
verwertet werden, wenn kumulativ zwei Voraussetzungen erfüllt sind: Einerseits wird verlangt, dass von Privaten
erlangte Beweismittel von den Strafverfolgungsbehörden rechtmässig hätten erlangt werden können; andererseits muss
eine Interessenabwägung für deren Verwertung sprechen.
In Bezug auf Beweismittel, die von den Strafverfolgungsbehörden rechtswidrig erhoben wurden, nimmt die StPO diese
Interessenabwägung selber vor. Demnach dürfen solche Beweise nur dann verwertet werden, wenn dies zur Aufklärung
einer schweren Straftat unerlässlich ist.
Es erscheint angesichts dieser Rechtsprechung angemessen, den gleichen Massstab auch bei rechtswidrig erlangten
Beweismitteln von Privaten anzuwenden, zumal es aus Sicht der betroffenen Person keine Rolle spielt, durch wen die
Beweise erhoben wurden, mit denen sie im Strafverfahren konfrontiert wird.
Im vorliegenden Fall wurde das Verhalten der Automobilistin vom Obergericht teils als einfache, teils als grobe
Verletzung der Verkehrsregeln qualifiziert. Bei diesen Delikten handelt es sich nicht um schwere Straftaten im
Sinne der StPO.
Die Interessenabwägung fällt damit gegen eine Verwertung der Aufnahmen als Beweis aus. Offen bleiben kann unter
diesen Voraussetzungen, ob auch die weitere für eine Verwertung der fraglichen Aufnahmen erforderliche Bedingung
erfüllt wäre, dass die Aufzeichnungen von den Strafverfolgungsbehörden rechtmässig hätten erlangt werden können.

English translation done by llama3.1:8b on my own computer with the prompt "Übersetze diesen Text nach Englisch, beachte, dass Obergericht als "Appellation Court" genannt wird und Bundesgericht als "supreme court": ...". No guarantee that the English text is correct.

Verdict based on Dashcam recordings: Driver's complaint upheld by Supreme Court
The Supreme Court has overturned the verdict of a driver who was convicted of repeated violations of traffic
rules based on dashcam recordings from another road user. As evidence, the use of recordings obtained in violation
of the Data Protection Act is already ruled out because the alleged traffic offenses are not serious crimes.
Whether the use of such recordings would be admissible as evidence in the case of a serious crime had to be
decided by the Supreme Court. The woman was convicted by the district court of Bülach in 2018 on the basis of
dashcam recordings from another road user for multiple, partly gross violations of traffic rules, and sentenced to
a conditional fine and a fine of CHF 4,000. The Appellation Court of the Canton of Zurich confirmed the verdict.
The Supreme Court upheld the complaint of the woman and overturned the verdict of the Appellation Court. The
private dashcam recordings were obtained in violation of the Data Protection Act (DSG) and are therefore unlawful.
Since the creation of recordings from a vehicle for other road users is not easily recognizable, it involves
secret data processing within the meaning of Article 4(4) DSG, which constitutes an invasion of personality.
The Criminal Procedure Code (StPO) contains provisions on the admissibility of evidence obtained by state
authorities in violation of the law. However, the StPO does not explicitly regulate to what extent these bans on
evidence also apply if private parties collect evidence.
According to case law of the Supreme Court, only evidence collected by private individuals may be used as
evidence if two cumulative conditions are met: On the one hand, evidence obtained by private individuals must have
been obtainable by the investigating authorities in a lawful manner; on the other hand, an interest balance must
speak in favor of its use.
In cases where evidence was obtained by state authorities in violation of the law, the StPO conducts this
interest balancing itself. Therefore, such evidence may only be used if it is necessary for the clarification of a
serious crime.
Considering this case law, it seems appropriate to apply the same standard to evidence collected by private
individuals as well, since it does not make a difference from the point of view of the person concerned who
collects the evidence with which they are confronted in the criminal proceedings.
In the present case, the behavior of the motorist was qualified by the Appellation Court partly as a simple and
partly as a gross violation of traffic rules. These offenses are not serious crimes within the meaning of the
StPO.
The interest balance thus falls against the use of the recordings as evidence. Remaining open is whether also
the further condition required for the use of the recordings, that they could have been obtained by the
investigating authorities in a lawful manner, would be fulfilled.


I don't have any citation ready, but I would assume it would be the same in [tag:germany].

@JörgWMittag In 2018, the BGH allowed dashcam footage as evidence (in a civil matter) even though iits recording was a breach of data protection: https://juris.bundesgerichtshof.de/cgi-bin/rechtsprechung/document.py?Gericht=bgh&Art=pm&pm_nummer=0088/18 I don't know if there is anything definite on criminal trials.
